# Playlists with YouTube iframe API no longer work?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, playlist

It seems that YouTube has done some changes to the YouTube iframe API. Unfortunately I'm no longer able to embed a YT playlist with a defined starting (index) number.
Until today, the following simple code played a complete playlist in a queue, started with the 4th video of the list.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <title>
            YT video player
        </title>
        <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: 'videoseries',
        events: {
            onReady: loadPlaylist
        }
    });
}

function loadPlaylist() {
    player.loadPlaylist({
        playlist: "PL6E443347ECEF351E",
        listType: "playlist",
        index: 4
    });
}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
          <div id="player"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I gave it a couple of tries to fix it, but I wasn't successfully, yet. Do you have a clue to resolve this, please?

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround setting the "Suggested Quality" anything except default.

It's filed and you can track it from https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5411

Comment: Thanks, that helped! Any idea, to activate autoplay?
  playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1 }
This doesn't work for me.

Comment: I think it would make it a lot easier if you guys would have pointed out that the property that people will need to use for this "Suggested Quality" is "suggestedQuality" as even the source link doesn't make this implicitly clear (until you hit the reference links in the solutions down the page).